# Visual Studio python console

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have just installed Visual Studio 2019 and when I run a script inmediately launches the Python console, and closes after the script is finished.

I would like to know if it is possible to avoid the python console, since I have on parallel the Console from Visual Studio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when running some Python script in VS Code, you have to create `launch.json` file. It's a debug configuration. If there is no such a file, VS Code would ask you to create it automatically based on a template. The file then should have such a property: `"console": "integratedTerminal"` inside `"configurations"` array.
You can read more here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging